# How to replace a value at selected line to an existing file java

Tags: java, io

Which class would be best to use in this case and what method should I call to replace a value at specified line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to read all the lines, then write them back out, with the specified line modified. So `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` would be your main weapons.

Comment: Thanks on them "weapons". :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of *Kayaman* is wrong.

1. In the programming there are in most cases many solutions. That's why "The only way is ..." is wrong.
2. The solution of *Kayaman* will only work for very smal files whose size is smaller than the available Java heap size. But then it should be specified in the problem description, like "max file size is 1MB, JVM heap size is 128MB". If you run Java with 256MB heap and your file is 20GB it will just not work.
3. Even reading and writing line by line may not work, because lines can be longer than the heap size.

Comment: Well, these facts are true. However, that file is a config file, which size definitely in this case is not going to be larger then 1MB.

Comment: @nellykvist: You have not mentioned it is a config file. For a config yes, normally this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
until eof
   read line
   increment line number 
   if the line number is the specified line
       replace content
   end if
   write the modified line
```

end until

Comment: Thanks on quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the line number then use the BufferedWriter class to get to the line number and then use the BufferedWriter object to write the new line on the same line number which contains the existing line.

If you don not know the number before hand then you would need to read the File first using BufferedReader, arrive at the line number and then replace the line number following the steps above.